# Call disconnecting just after dialing while using call intent from service

Tags: android

I'm trying to initiate a call from background service. Its working fine on sony xperia p android ics. But in `samsung galaxy y android 2.3.3` call gets disconnected automatically just after initiating.

```
String number=Utils.getNumber(this, "contact"+i); 

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Note its working properly on sony xperia p

Comment: post logcat to aid better understanding

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the response. I have solved the issue. Call was disconnected since i was trying to message together with initiating call. Now message is send after the call. So its working properly. Don't know why is it so but its working now :)